# What does this phrase about producing randomized online surveys mean?

Tags: survey

In regards to online surveys, there are 3 basic types of questions -  single punch, multi-punch, and grid qualification. The grid type is basically a series of single-punch  questions -  maybe to rate a restaurants food, decor, air, etc.

So I'm asked to:

> Allow the ability to randomize the responses for single punch,
>   multi-punch, and grid qualification types(including the ability to
>   anchor certain ones).

I think I get the randomized part - just make random answers. I'm confused at what "anchor certain ones" means.

Comment: You'll probably need to ask whoever gave you that mandate, but I'd guess that it means to have certain choices always show up in certain spots.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that makes sense to me! thanks a lot J08691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So j08691 was right - it means to have certain choices always show up in certain spots . Usually the choice "none of above".